# Give an example of non split short exact sequence $0\to M\to\Bbb{Z}[X]\to M'\to 0$ of $\Bbb{Z}$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

> Give an example of $\Bbb{Z}$-modules $M,M'$ such that $0\to
>  M\to\Bbb{Z}[X]\to M'\to0$ is
>
> - (a) split short exact,
> - (b) non split short exact

For (a), take $M=\langle X\rangle=\{Xf(X):\ f(X)\in\Bbb{Z}[X]\}$ and $M'=\Bbb{Z}$ and $0\to \langle X\rangle \hookrightarrow\Bbb{Z}[X]\to \Bbb{Z}[X]/\langle X\rangle\cong \Bbb{Z}\to 0$ is split short exact.

But I am unable to produce an example for (b). Can anyone give me a hint or wayout? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hint, if it does split, then the module in the middle is the direct sum of its two neighbors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $M=\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $M' = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[X]$, with the map $M \to \mathbb{Z}[X]$ being multiplication by $2$. The sequence can't be split, since any map from $M'$ to $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is zero (why?).

Comment: The image of the map $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[X]$ given by multiplication by $2$ is the principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ generated by $2$, and so the quotient is not $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ but rather $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[X]$. Still, your idea works fine if you just take $M = \langle 2, X \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}[X]$, and the first map to be the inclusion $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed an $X$. This is just the classical non-split sequence for $\mathbb{Z}$ with an $X$ adjoint. Not sure why I thought the $X$ would have been quotiented out :O